# Why putting pointer* for Strings not for Integers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop

I learnt Swift firstly , maybe this should have been after learning Obj-C, so now I trying full understand Obj-C, I have trouble with issue below :

Obj-C variables

```
NSInteger score = 556;
NSString *name = @"matt";
```

in Swift everything is same for variables

```
var score = 556
var name = "matt"
```

Why objective-c use for strings * although integers are not * using, Why there is a such a different ? It is related run time ?

Can you explain to me  with practical examples ? Thanks

Comment: It's similar to the difference between a value type and a reference type in Swift (note that in Swift arrays and strings are value types, but in Objective-C they are reference types). It's about allocating memory on the stack or on the heap.
Frankly, this is rather a big topic of memory management.

Comment: @Sulthan thank you. 
,Cy-4AH it would be nice , recommend specific reference to help me rather than close.

Comment: Swift's `var score = 556` it's objective's `NSNumber *score = @556;`

Comment: @Cy-4AH No, `var score = 556` is both `NSNumber *score = @556` and `NSInteger score = 556` in Objective-C.

Comment: FWIW. In general terms, a pointer *points* to a location in memory. That memory was allocated and is where something of interest is stored. So here the object ```@"matt"``` is allocated and stored somewhere and ```name``` points to that location. Without ARC you'd need to release or free it at some stage, but with ARC that is taken care of.

Comment: On the other hand, ```score``` does not occupy some specially allocated place in memory. A variable such as ```score``` is stored on the stack and will be automatically discarded when it goes out of scope - no special memory management requirements. Also, ```score``` can be accessed directly - its value can be accessed as is. An object's value can not be accessed like that, it has to be read or written from memory, so that is why it will always be referenced by a pointer, while something such as an integer can be accessed directly or you could allocate some space and store ints there also.

Comment: @skaak your last comment is very useful simple explanation but tells lots of things to me. If you have time you are welcomed drop an answer with some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know, without pointers Objective-C is just Swift with semicolons.

Suppose you need to allocate a region of memory for your own use. You can store integers there, or an image, or a dictionary of objects or a sound clip. The pointer is your handle on that piece of memory. It tells you primarily the location of the region of memory you got, but in Objective-C, it also keeps track of e.g. a reference count so that you do not need to worry about allocating and releasing it. So things can get pretty complex pretty quick.

Let us assume the simplest possible scenario. You need some memory to store an object. Say a string, but that does not matter. Also, to all the purists out there, this is a general discussion not meant to be technically correct, but to illustrate the idea to OP.

First you will alloc that object

```
NSString * p = [NSString alloc];
```

This will ask the OS for a region of memory of the correct size to store a string and the OS will respond with a pointer that points to the newly allocated area, that address now stored in `p`. This is just an area of memory and you can do what you want with it. You need not even store a string there but things can go pear shaped pretty quick if you wander off like that.

Now the OS just gave you a region of memory. That memory is not blank, it holds some left over bits from whatever it was used for before. So your first task is to clear the memory - to initialise it. So the next step is to initialise it

```
p = [p init];
```

After this the area of memory has been *prepared* by some initialiser, e.g. it was zeroed or loaded some default values into the area of memory for a more complex class.

Note in reality this is a bit different - see the edit below.

In C you have `alloc` and `malloc` and `calloc` to do this. Some of these will just allocate memory and others will allocate the memory and set it all to 0 - clearing all the bits. In Objective-C you typically do this as a single step

```
p = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Since the OS allocated a region of memory you need to tell it when you are done to free it, e.g.

```
[p release];
```

or in C you'd use `free` when done.

Now this is just academic, as ARC will do this automatically for you by keeping an internal reference counter to the object to determine when it goes out of scope and then to release it, but I digress. Let us just for now assume you need not worry about releasing that block of memory back to the OS, ARC will take care of it for you.

Let us also for now assume a more complex class, say

```
p = [[Invoice alloc] init];
```

Then when you e.g. do

```
p.items = 100;
```

the compiler will know that it needs to *copy* the integer value of `100` to the correct place inside that block of memory and it will do so for you. There are many variations on this theme, but basically as you assign values to ivars those values gets copied into the allocated area of memory and as you read them they get copied back from the correct spot into the local variable as well.

On the other hand, if you assign a value to a simple int variable

```
int items = 100;
```

this is not copied to your pre-allocated area. In stead, the message or function has a special local working area called a stack where these variables are created and later discarded dynamically. So the statement above will load the value `100` onto the stack and will note the position so that later if you refer to `items` it will know where to find and read or write its value on the stack.

Likewise

```
Invoice * p = [[Invoice alloc] init];
```

is loaded on the stack, but here the *pointer's value* or memory address is loaded on the stack, not the contents it points to. The fact that it is a pointer indicates to you that it points to some region of interest somewhere else.

If later you do

```
Invoice * q = p;
```

you load (on the stack) the same pointer value of p into q, and now p and q both point to the same area of memory where the actual object is stored. So pointers add this one layer of separation between the value of the pointer that can be interpreted as pointing to an address in memory, and the data that is stored at this address. This can go on, e.g. you can and do get pointers to pointers and so on.

Since you can not allocate memory yourself on the dynamic stack, you can not store objects on the stack, but you can store pointers to objects there.

Pointers give you incredible power as you access memory directly. You can e.g. write a general function to allocate memory or to write memory to disk or to clear memory or to transfer a block of memory through the network or to load a block of memory to a screen area. Modern compilers take care of these things for us so it does not sound like such a big deal, but the powerful thing is that you use the same routine for all your objects. If your array stores pointers then you can store anything in the array as another example.

Pointers also outlive the stack. The stuff you put on the stack e.g.

```
int items = 100;
```

only survives as long as you are inside the function. The stack is discarded when the function returns so you need a specially allocated area of memory to communicate in a way that transcends functions and sometimes even applications.

Here is a deeper example, using only integer pointers, not Objective-C object ones, to further illustrate the difference between pointers and values on the stack.

In C you'd do

```
int * p = malloc ( 10 * sizeof( int ) );
```

which will allocate enough space to store 10 integers and return the pointer to the allocated space in `p`. `p` is now on the stack and contains the address of the area of memory just returned.

Next if you do

```
int q = 123;
```

the value 123 is stored onto the stack and under the moniker `q` which the compiler will translate to this specific location on the stack as you work with `q` e.g. assign a value to it.

Next, if you do

```
* p = q;
* ( p + 1 ) = q / 2;
```

this will load the value of `q` (123) from the stack and into the area of memory pointed to by `p`, which points to the first of the 10 integers. Next you calculate `q / 2` and store that value into the location of the next integer, the 1 after the first, pointed to by `p` and referenced by `* ( p + 1 )`. The compiler can do this easily as it knows the size of an integer so it knows how to translate

```
* ( p + 1 )
```

into the correct area that points to the integer shifted 1 away from the base `p`.

This is another topic with pointers, it allows for incredibly efficient pointer arithmetic that you can use to traverse areas of memory. Also, this is why `sizeof` is such an important keyword in C as it is directly linked to how the language handles memory through pointers.

In C, when done, you need to release the area back to the OS so you'd do

```
free( p );
```

when done.

This seems simple enough, but in practise it is difficult to keep track of all the allocated regions of memory. It easily happens that you do not release one or that you load data into an area already released. The former leaks memory and the latter can have disasterous consequences.

This is why Objective-C's ARC represents such a big step in the development of the language as it takes care of this for you. In the ARC world the allocation and freeing of memory, a BIG topic in pointers, is no longer that important or visible - so it can also shield some understanding of pointers from its users.

In e.g. Swift this allocation and freeing happens completely behind the scenes and you do not really worry about allocating or freeing memory directly. This makes it difficult to understand the difference between pointing to memory and the memory being pointed to, which is at the heart of pointers.

You know, without pointers Objective-C is just Swift with semicolons.

I started and now ended with this somewhat controversial statement.

Why?

When I was a programmer struggling with the concept of pointers, I had a mind to give it up completely. This was before objects and you could (try to) do all you needed to on the stack and side step pointers that way.

I just came from Pascal (where you do not use pointers that much) and struggled with C, especially with pointers, and then read somewhere that, without pointers, C is just Pascal with curly braces! I knew C was powerful, more so than Pascal, but to grasp for that I had to master pointers.

Note - as mentioned by Sulthan, Pascal also has pointers and it is very debatable if one is more powerful than the other.

Here is a nice sample to illustrate a lot of these concepts, also how you can use pointers to iterate through memory.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // insert code here...
        int a = 10;      // a loaded on stack
        int * b = & a;   // b now points to a

        NSLog ( @"a pointer %p value %d", & a, a );
        NSLog ( @"b value %p points to %d", b, * b );

        int * p = malloc ( 10 * sizeof ( int ) );
        int * q = p;

        // Show p on the stack and * p allocated somewhere
        // Note the values, & p agrees with & a of earlier e.g.
        NSLog ( @"p address %p on stack but points to %p", & p, p );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
        {
            * q = i; // loads value i into area pointed to by q

            NSLog ( @"i now %d", i );
            // Note the huge difference between addresses on the stack and addresses alloc'd
            NSLog ( @"\tp %p p + i %p value pointed to is %d", p, p + i, * ( p + i ) );
            NSLog ( @"\tq %p value pointed to is %d", q, * q );

            q ++;       // Increment pointer, not value, now points to next int
        }

        // Of course ...
        free ( p );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT Objective-C alloc**

I mention in the text that the memory needs to be initialised after an Objective-C alloc. I could not find any documentation now, but I am pretty sure that Objective-C's `alloc`, e.g. something like

```
NSString * s = [NSString alloc];
```

will in fact *both* allocate *and* clear or zero the memory. The `init` is not really meant to zero but for the class to initialise its members properly.

But, since we are discussing pointers and since you are looking for programming examples, what better than to write a piece of code to test this.

The code below will create two Objective-C classes of your choice. One will only be alloc'd and one will be alloc'd and init'd. Then it compares these two classes byte for byte using pointers to see if there is a difference. Another nice example of using pointers.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

// The object we will test
#define TEST_OBJECT NSFileManager

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Allocate some complex class
        TEST_OBJECT * obja = [TEST_OBJECT alloc];
        TEST_OBJECT * obji = [[TEST_OBJECT alloc] init];

        // Size of this class
        unsigned long n = class_getInstanceSize ( TEST_OBJECT.class );

        NSLog ( @"Object size is %lu", n );
        NSLog ( @"\tLocation in memory %p", obja );
        NSLog ( @"\t                   %p", obji );

        // Get pointers to the two instances
        void * p = ( __bridge void * ) obja;
        void * q = ( __bridge void * ) obji;

        // Compare the two
        int cmp = memcmp( p, q, n );

        NSLog ( @"Result is %d - %@", cmp, cmp ? @"different" : @"same" );

        // Dump the actual bytes side by side
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
        {
            int l = ( unsigned ) ( * ( ( unsigned char * ) p + i ) );   // Left
            int r = ( unsigned ) ( * ( ( unsigned char * ) q + i ) );   // Right

            NSLog ( @"Byte %3d | %3d | %3d | %@", i, l, r, l != r ? @"***" : @"" );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pascal also has pointers and they are a big thing there too. C is not really more powerful than Pascal.

Comment: @Sulthan yes very true - I have updated my answer.

Comment: I understand that "C is Pascal with curly braces" helped you, but "Objective-C is Swift with semicolons" isn't controversial, it's just wrong for reasons far beyond the use of explicit pointers. C and Pascal were created within a few years of each other and reflected the computing environments that they grew up in. Objective-C predates Swift by about 30 years, and being derived from C it carried a lot of even older baggage around; Swift is a much more modern language with support for several different programming styles.

Comment: @Caleb thanks - I know that statement is provocative which is why I took care to explain it. I was looking for ```x``` in "Obj-C without pointers is like Swift with/without ```x``` but I agree it does not work as well as it does with C and Pascal - unless there is perhaps a better ```x```. I think what is relevant here is the fact that Swift shields you from pointers and Obj-C does not, rather than the difference in age or anything else between the two. At the time I encountered the original statement that was also the difference between C and Pascal that it highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the difference between a value type and a reference type in Swift, then in Objective-C using a pointer simply denotes a reference type.

During assignments, either the *value* is copied:

```
// swift
var score = 10
// obj-c
NSInteger score = 10;
```

or the *reference* is copied, or, in other words, we are not assigning the value itself but the *pointer* to the value:

```
// swift
class MyObject {}

var object = MyObject();

// obj-c
@interface MyObject: NSObject
@end

MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

Also note that in Objective-C string (`NSString`), arrays (`NSArray`) and similar are all reference types. Even numeric types which are value types (`NSInteger`) have reference type wrappers (e.g. `NSNumber`) because otherwise you cannot put them into an array. Even `null` value has a corresponding reference type `NSNull`.

Of course, even with value types you can use a pointer:

```
NSInteger score = 10;
NSInteger *scorePointer = &score; // assign pointer to score
*scorePointer = 20; // change value of score through the pointer

NSLog(@"%@", @(score)); // 20
```

In the same way you can also have pointers to other pointers, which is useful in many situations (e.g. inout method parameters).

Comment: This is a good explanation for someone coming from Swift, but I'm afraid it gives the impression that Obj-C uses pointers in order to achieve reference types, and that's not really true. Objective-C uses pointers because that's how it implements it's object model, and it inherits the value semantics of its non-object types from C. The designers of Swift recognized that both kinds of values are useful and made the distinction explicit in their new language.

Comment: @Caleb I just tried to simplify the explanation to a given level of understanding :)